# Reload HTML table after sorting list (ejs/js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm writing a personal project that displays data, previously gathered in a sqlite3 database, through a node application.
Since I don't plan to make a commercial application and the data has no privacy issues, right now I'm just:

- loading the data from the database into a list
- displaying the list in a html table populated through ejs.

**What I would like to do is:** sorting the table by clicking on headers.

I had found a function to do so [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp) but the dataset I'm working with has grown in number and apparently that function doesn't work any more. (Whenever I try using it the page just starts loading and never completes, I've tried limiting the data to the first 20 examples and it works again).

What I've though about doing is using a basic javascript ".sort" function and then reloading the whole table rather than interacting with the single rows. I have no problems writing the sorting part but I don't know how to refresh the table display, I only know how to create it the first time through ejs:

```
<% auctionRows.forEach((row)=>{ %>
    <tr>
       <td class="fill"><%=row.server%></td>
       <td class="compress"><%=row.itemname%></td>
       <td class="compress"><%=row.lvl%></td>
       <td class="compress"><%=row.price%></td>
       <td class="compress rightest"><%=row.bonus%></td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
```

Can the display part be moved to a function that I can call again after I sort?
Is there a better solution?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I ended up serving the data through a dedicated route and getting it through an ajax get request so that I could then manipulate it directly within Javascript.
I then created a function that from the data would display a table and whenever I needed to change something I would re-order / filter the data and then call the display function again.